# Is there any command line tool for breaking a single JavaScript file into multiple smaller files?

Tags: javascript, command-line, automation

Provided I have a huge JavaScript file I would like to find a tool that automatically, by specifying MAX_SIZE, for instance, converts that file into a set of smaller files.

Does that kind of tool exist?  Would it be easy to implement such a tool?

Comment: I doubt it. It would be relatively complex to implement (given the language supports variable and function hoisting) and I can't imagine that there are many usecases for splitting JS up by *size*.

Comment: the codes will be broken if max_size is reached and it is in the middle of function or statement or variable, causing  a syntax error.

Comment: Why? Seems easier and safer to break it up yourself, and preserve human-significant semantic meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a tool exists, and trying to create one would be a huge can of worms. You obviously cannot break up the code at a specific size, since that would most likely happen in the middle of some function or other. Therefore, such a tool would need to be able to parse javascript in order to not break it. Even worse, there would be no guarantee whatsoever that the functions in different files would have anything to do with each other. A function in one file could depend on constants and functions defined in any number of other files, which in turn would depend on other files, resulting in a colossal mess.

If you need to break your code up into smaller files, start grouping semantically related functions and form classes out of them, and determine their dependencies on other files. This can only be done by a human programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer, a logical subdivision should be done by a programmer.
Also, I guess there would be no advantage at all in breaking a file into more files, without removing anything, as you only would get some web transfer overhead.

By the way, to reply to the question without asking...
actually you could.

Most common JS libraries are made of a single huge object declaration, effectively being a single top-level statement script, as in

```
libraryname = {
    fn1: function() { /* do something */ },
    fn2: function() { /* do something else */ },
    fn3: function() { /* do something else */ }
}
```

This is the reason why you can't trivially split the file into two valid script files.

The code can be split anyway into non js valid chunks, if recombined before execution.
Just split the code into many text files, retrieve them separately, then concatenate the strings in the right order and then load it into the page.
Loading it can be done in more than one way, depending on what you want to accomplish.
You can either create a new script element and append it to the head element, or call eval on it.

The code could look something like this (even if it could be optimized):

```
function loadScript(name, n) {
    var chunks = new Array(n);
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++)
        chunks[i] = getChunk(name, i); // simple blocking ajax call retrieving chunk content
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.innerHTML = chunks.join('');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```